# From JSon array to custom data structure

Tags: android, json, gson

Say I need to fill a Binary Search Tree with data obtained from Server. Say further that the data coming from server is a json array of nodes

```
 "parts":[{"id":1,"name":"apple"},{"id":12,"name":"orange"},{"id":21,"name":"pen"},{"id":214,"name":"kite"}]//where each {} represents a node
```

How do I use GSon to read the array of Nodes into my BST?

If you recall a BST has two classes

```
public class BST{
    private Note root;
}

public class Node{
  String el;
  Node left, right;
}
```

If BST is too hard, image something simpler

```
public class MyDataStructure{
   private List<Part> partsList;
   …
}

public class Part{
  String el;
  List<String> stuff;
}
```

How do I populate MyDataStructure with `partsList` using GSon on android? As a side note, I would rather help solving the MyDataStruction version of the problem.

Comment: post an example how the json can look like... so we can help you to bild the pojos....

Comment: I have updated. But feel free to imagine as simple a json as you wish. The real problem is beyond the json itself. I already told you it's an array.

Comment: How is the BST mapped to the array? Depth-first? Or are you supposed to figure out the relations between the nodes via the ids?

Answer (score 1):

ok.. you can use this as reference:

define a class pojo
and a Fruit(is the array/list/collection)

## the pojo

```
class Pojo {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pojo [parts=" + parts + "]";
    }
    private List<Fruits> parts;
}
```

## the fruit

```
class Fruits {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

## the implementation

```
String json = "{\"parts\": [{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"apple\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"pear\"},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"kiwi\"}]}";
Gson g = new Gson();
Pojo p = g.fromJson(json, Pojo.class);
System.out.println(p);
```

## the MyDataStructure population

add to the pojo a setter getter so you can work with the list, add too setter and getter for the fruit class so you can get the id and the name..

so in the pojo object p you can do p.getList() and iterate over the elements

Something like:

```
Pojo p = g.fromJson(json, Pojo.class);
System.out.println(p);
for (Fruits f : p.getParts()) {
    System.out.println(f.getId());
    System.out.println(f.getName());
}
```